# Process.Start() Exception

Tags: vb.net, windows-8.1

I can not run some applications located inside system32 folder using vb.net

```
Process.Start("C:\Windows\system32\SnippingTool.exe")
Process.Start("C:\Windows\system32\StikyNot.exe")
```

The debugger show the message: Win32Exception the system cannot find the file specified.

However these addresses work correctly running through a shortcut or when I paste them into the address bar of the Windows Explorer.

**Edit**: After a lot of research I have found the solution for this problem, see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16827229/file-not-found-error-launching-system32-winsat-exe-using-process-start), the answer from Simon MᶜKenzie. Thank you all for the help.

Comment: Are you running the project as Admin?

Comment: Running as admin makes no difference.

Comment: I have edited your title. Please see, "[Should questions include “tags” in their titles?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19190/)", where the consensus is "no, they should not".

Comment: Set a breakpoint at and see if the string is being correctly passed. I can't remember if vb wants strings with double delimiters.

Comment: System32 is in the Path environment variable. You should be able to execute those apps without the path.

Comment: John, I have taken note of that, sorry for the mistake. Mathemats, using double delimiters makes no difference too. Thanks. This is driving me crazy, some exe's from system32 can run and some can not. I have been checking the Security Tab, from Properties Dialog, they are all equal.

Comment: Hi, tinstaafl, with or without the path I got the same results, just some exe's can't start, for example SnippingTool.exe. Some others just run fine, like write.exe (worldpad)... and it seems they have exactly the same set of permissions. Would be nice if someone can replicate this behavior or is just my notebook.

Comment: possible duplicate of ["File not found" error launching system32\winsat.exe using Process.Start()](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16827229/file-not-found-error-launching-system32-winsat-exe-using-process-start)

Answer (score 2):

these lines are enough to do this:

```
 Process.Start("StikyNot")
 Process.Start("SnippingTool")
```

for additional reference http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/53ezey2s%28v=vs.110%29.aspx