# Unable to run nbtstat using System.Diagnostic.Process

Tags: c#, networking, command-prompt

I have a working piece of code which executes commands using System.Diagnostic.Process. However, when I try to run nbtstat using the same code it does not return anything (neither is there an exception). When I run hostname (as an example) it returns the hostname.

```
 string result = "";
            //string commandToExec = "hostname";
            string commandToExec = "nbtstat -A 10.10.10.5";
            System.Diagnostics.ProcessStartInfo procStartInfo =
                new System.Diagnostics.ProcessStartInfo("C:\\Windows\\System32\\cmd.exe", "/c " + commandToExec);
            procStartInfo.RedirectStandardOutput = true;
            procStartInfo.UseShellExecute = false;
            procStartInfo.CreateNoWindow = true;
            System.Diagnostics.Process proc = new System.Diagnostics.Process();
            proc.StartInfo = procStartInfo;
            proc.Start();
            result = proc.StandardOutput.ReadToEnd();
```

This command

```
nbtstat -A 10.10.10.5
```

works perfectly well from the command prompt. I am not able to understand the problem, neither find resources on the net which could help. If anyone can guide me in the right direction please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should call the nbtstat.exe program directly, there is no need to invoke CMD to call it.  So use this line instead;

```
System.Diagnostics.ProcessStartInfo procStartInfo = new System.Diagnostics.ProcessStartInfo(@"c:\windows\sysnative\nbtstat.exe", "-A 10.10.10.5");
```

I also use Sysnative because of Windows64bit redirection.  As exaplained in [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16827229/file-not-found-error-launching-system32-winsat-exe-using-process-start)

Comment: Thanks ... for the answer and pointing to the reason for the behaviour.