# Process cannot find file specified

Tags: c#, process, architecture, 32bit-64bit

I have the following issue:

I have a C# app that runs as a 32-bit Application on my 64-Bit Machine. This application opens a process and starts `wbadmin` to make a backup of the C drive.

Now: when I call enter `"wbadmin"` in the command line `wbadmin` works and shows lists all its commands.

In my c# app when i do

```cs
ProcessStartInfo info = new ProcessStartInfo("wbadmin", $"start backup -backupTarget:{destinationDrive} -include:C: -quiet -vssCopy")
{
    UseShellExecute = false
};

Process p = new Process()
{
    StartInfo = info,
    EnableRaisingEvents = true
};

p.Start();
```

it tells me that the file specified cannot be found. 
I did some research and I think my app is looking for the `wbadmin` in the `WOW64` folder, where it cant find it because it is inside the `System32` Folder.

How do I tell my program to use the correct `wbadmin.exe` in the correct location?

Do I HAVE to run the app as a 64-bit application for it to work?
If so how would i support 32-bit architecture?

Thanks

Comment: are you sure that your app *is* 32-bit? what does `Environment.Is64BitProcess` say?

Comment: You can specify `WorkingDirectory` for your `ProcessStartInfo`, have a look at [msdn](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.diagnostics.processstartinfo.workingdirectory?view=netframework-4.8)

Comment: @MarcGravell Environment.Is64BitProcess is false. I Debug in Visual Studio with the setting AnyCPU

Comment: @PavelAnikhouski What would i set the WorkingDirectory to? System32? Wouldnt this be automatically changed to WOW64 when my app is running as 32Bit?

Comment: @calgara12 Yes, try to specify `system32` or use absolute path to `wbadmin`. Also check how did you run it from command line, with admin rights or not.

Comment: @PavelAnikhouski i already enabled admin rights in my application. I get the same error(The file specified cannot be found) when i set my Working Directory to System32 Any other ideas what the problem could be?

Comment: @calgara12 you should use `sysnative` in `wbadmin` path, it is explained in this [thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16827229/file-not-found-error-launching-system32-winsat-exe-using-process-start) There is a different executable, but the same problem

Comment: @PavelAnikhouski Thanks, now it runs. Another question. Say i run this program on a 32 Bit architecture, would this still run?

Comment: @calgara12 32bit Windows OS doesn't have sysnative folder, afaik. And I don't about `wbadmin` for 32bit arch

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to @PavelAnikhouski for providing me with the correct answer.

I had to specify the path to sysnative.